# why ssh not route outgoing packages (pptp)?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, pptp, tunneling, pptpd

I have VPS #1 that pptpd and sshuttle installed on it and VPS #2 that have ssh access to it
I need to rout trafic from VPS#1 to VPS#2 (by tunnel because pptp not available to vps#2) for users that use pptp to connect to VPS#1 , I use sshuttle for tunnel between VPS#1 and VPS#2 to send data but it's not working ...

is it theorical worng or I miss something here ?

---

in other word i quote from [this](http://www.randomhacks.co.uk/how-to-route-all-your-network-traffic-through-an-ssh-tunnel/) :

The usage of 0/0 routes all the traffic except DNS requests to the remote server.  If you need to tunnel your DNS too ...

so why pptp trafic not rout to the server i want ?